# How to parse csv file with camel bindy, when some columns have quotes and some not?

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, bindy

I try to use Camel bindy to process my csv file. Rows of the file look like this:

```
1111;"2016-06-21";"12:15";"Test1";"1";
2222;"2016-06-21";"12:16";"Test2";"2";
```

My model file is:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ";")
public class CsvBean implements Serializable {

    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private Integer key;

    @DataField(pos = 2, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;

    @DataField(pos = 3, pattern = "hh-mm")
    private Date time;

    @DataField(pos = 4)
    private String title;

    @DataField(pos = 5)
    private int status;
}
```

and I use unmarshall(bindy) method. The exception I got is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parsing error detected for field defined at the position: 3, line: 1
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyCsvFactory.bind(BindyCsvFactory.java:207)
```

I suppose that the problem is that first "id" value is without quotes and the rest of columns have. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern for pos 3 is wrong . Try the below code

```
 @DataField(pos = 3, pattern = "hh:mm")
```

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you very much!